# Laravel 5.5: PHPUnit (with coverage) doesn't like routes from multiple files and throws "A facade root has not been set". Without coverage it's green

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.5, php-7

I have Laravel 5.5 where I decided to group routes in files to organise them in a more meaningful way.

Here's a simplified example - the web route files live in:

```
app/Http/Routes/Web/static.php
app/Http/Routes/Web/test.php
```

**static.php** contains:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Foo\Http\Routes\Web;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**test.php** contains:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Foo\Http\Routes\Web;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'test'; // just to simplify
});
```

**RouteServiceProvider.php** contains:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Foo\App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'Foo\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    }

    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function($router) {
            require app_path('Http/Routes/Web/static.php');
            require app_path('Http/Routes/Web/test.php');
            // more files will land here in the future
        });
    }
}
```

Up to now I can confirm that everything works by calling `php artisan route:list`:

[image]

Now I was going to write some tests but I require code coverage, so I added:

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./report" charset="UTF-8"
         yui="true" highlight="true"
         lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
</logging>
```

into my `phpunit.xml`.

When I call `phpunit` I get:

```
PHPUnit 7.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /Users/slick/Code/foo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:218
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/slick/Code/foo/app/Http/Routes/Web/static.php(10): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('get', Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/7.0.1/libexec/phpunit-7.0.1.phar/php-code-coverage/CodeCoverage.php(929): include_once('/Users/slick/Co...')
#2 phar:///usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/7.0.1/libexec/phpunit-7.0.1.phar/php-code-coverage/CodeCoverage.php(243): SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage->initializeData()
#3 phar:///usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/7.0.1/libexec/phpunit-7.0.1.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php(671): SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage->start(Object(Tests\Feature\ExampleTest))
#4 phar:///usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/7.0.1/libexec/phpunit-7.0.1.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php(687): PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run(Object(Tests\Feature\ExampleTest))
#5 phar:///usr/local/Cell in /Users/slick/Code/foo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 218

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /Users/slick/Code/foo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 218
```

[image]

Straight after I remove the coverage lines I added to xml file and run `phpunit` again - it's green.

> $ phpunit PHPUnit 7.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> ..                                                                  2
>   / 2 (100%)
>
> Time: 381 ms, Memory: 20.00MB
>
> OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)

What's wrong? Why phpunit with code coverage doesn't like routes in multiple files (but without coverage it works perfectly fine)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Someone had the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366544/4197938) and fixed that by excluding routes directories from code coverage. So I added into `phpunit.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app/Http/Routes</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

And `phpunit` with coverage works good.

Goshh… facades are tricky.

Comment: Just ran into this as well. It looks like the PhpUnit code coverage class includes all files to receive the coverage, meaning if they're procedural like a routes file, they accidentally get executed on the spot. And since this process spins up before the app does, the ServiceProviders wouldn't have had a chance to define things like Facades.