# A facade root has not been set

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-facade, laravel-testing

- **Laravel 6.5**
- **Laravel Browser Kit ^5.1**

I am creating my own packages for something I building and one is causing the issue at hand: A facade root has not been set. when I run my tests.

This is routes file `App\Game\routes\web.php`:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// Core routes for the game related stuff:
Route::get('/game', ['as' => 'game', 'uses' => 'GameController@game']);
```

Pretty basic, nothing here that should stand out. So how do we register these:

```
<?php

namespace App\Game\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RoutesProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Game\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    }

    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(__DIR__.'/../routes/web.php');
    }
}
```

Again nothing insane, if we addd this to the `config/app.php` and run `php artisan route:list` we see:

[image]

You can see the game route above. so now lets run our tests, make sure nothings breaking ...

```
composer phpunit
> ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html=./test-coverage
PHPUnit 8.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:242
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/app/Game/routes/web.php(5): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('get', Array)
#1 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage.php(955): include_once('/Users/adambala...')
#2 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage.php(239): SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage->initializeData()
#3 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(646): SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage->start(Object(Tests\Unit\xxxx\BaseStatValueTest))
#4 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(752): PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run(Object(Tests\Unit\xxxx\BaseStatValueTest))
#5 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framewor in /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 242
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:242
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/app/Game/routes/web.php(5): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('get', Array)
#1 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage.php(955): include_once('/Users/adambala...')
#2 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage.php(239): SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage->initializeData()
#3 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(646): SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage->start(Object(Tests\Unit\xxxx\BaseStatValueTest))
#4 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(752): PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run(Object(Tests\Unit\xxxx\BaseStatValueTest))
#5 /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framewor in /Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 242
```

Its all caused by that `web.php` routes file when it tries to create the route doing: `Route::get(....)`. From my understanding `router` does not exist in app container when the app boots up for test.

I have tried calling `setUp` in my test classes, and calling it's parent. But still I get the error.

I have never encountered this before and nothing o the internet is helping me. Any ideas as to why I am getting this error?

Comment: and how are you registering this service provider?

Comment: The only way you would, in the config/app.php file @lagbox

Comment: since you are using browserkit i assume you are not using the default test case, how are you setting up the root test you are extending?

Comment: @lagbox  by following the instructions laravel browserkit gives you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Exclude the routes folder on phpunit coverage tests:

```xml
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>

            <exclude>
                <directory>./app/Game/routes</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
```

Comment: Why? Can you explain?

Comment: @TheWebs I don't know "why" but there are a lot of comments about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49093727/laravel-5-5-phpunit-with-coverage-doesnt-like-routes-from-multiple-files-and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357273/error-class-route-not-found-in-routes-php-when-testing-standalone-laravel-pac/47366544#47366544 https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26372 https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/a-facade-root-has-not-been-set-4