# Laravel PHP unit with code coverage giving error PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, php-code-coverage

I am getting following error

> PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in /var/www/html/checkout/routes/api.php:24

I have tried answer from [Error: Class 'Route' not found in routes.php when testing standalone Laravel package using Orchestra Testbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357273/error-class-route-not-found-in-routes-php-when-testing-standalone-laravel-pac). It is not working and giving same error.

Below is my XML code:

````
<filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./routes</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory >./routes</directory>
                 <file>./routes/api.php</file>
                 <file>./routes/web.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>```
````

Comment: `<file>./app/Http/routes/web.php</file>` try like this

Comment: still getting error after changes
 <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>./app/Http/routes/api.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

Comment: no just check this answer carefully - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49093727/laravel-5-5-phpunit-with-coverage-doesnt-like-routes-from-multiple-files-and

Answer (score 0):

My guess it becomes of aliases.
To fix this try to import `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;` class in the file where you are defining routes

Comment: inside ./routes/api.php added 
use Route;
getting error The use statement with non-compound name 'Route' has no effect

Comment: @Roshnijoshi have your specified the full name?
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my PHPUnit File

```
 <filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">/app/Http/Middleware</directory>
            <file>./app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php</file>
        </exclude>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">/app/Exceptions</directory>
            <file>./app/Exceptions/Handler.php</file>
        </exclude>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">/app/Helpers</directory>
            <file>./app/Helpers/Helpers.php</file>
        </exclude>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">/app/Providers</directory>
            <file>./app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php</file>
            <file>./app/Providers/HttpsProtocolProvider.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Partialy fixed by removing from test case

```
/**
  * @runInSeparateProcess
 */
```

added stderr="true" like bellow

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stderr="true">
```